# Python: AttributeError: Toplevel1 instance has no attribute 'Entry1'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When I try to open my Python script, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 111, in <module>
    vp_start_gui()
  File "gui.py", line 30, in vp_start_gui
    top = Toplevel1 (root)
  File "gui.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.Button1.configure(command=self.getTemp())
  File "gui.py", line 105, in getTemp
    this.plz = this.Entry1.get()
AttributeError: Toplevel1 instance has no attribute 'Entry1'
```

I googled the error but I haven't got any similar results.
Also, the attribute Entry1 exists as you can see in the code.
And I'm using the correct command to access Entry1.

Full code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 4.22
#  in conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Apr 24, 2019 01:22:16 PM CEST  platform: Darwin

import sys
import requests
import json

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import unknown_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = Toplevel1 (root)
    unknown_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Toplevel1 (w)
    unknown_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Toplevel1():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        key = "xxx" # API KEY von openweathermaps eintragen
        url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="
        parameters = ",DE&units=metric&appid=" + str(key)
        data = ""
        json = ""

        top.geometry("144x142+586+143")
        top.title("New Toplevel")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        self.Button1 = tk.Button(top)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.208, rely=0.352, height=32, width=77)
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(cursor="fleur")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''GET''')
        self.Button1.configure(width=77)
        self.Button1.configure(command=self.getTemp())

        self.Entry1 = tk.Entry(top)
        self.Entry1.place(relx=0.069, rely=0.07,height=27, relwidth=0.847)
        self.Entry1.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry1.configure(cursor="fleur")
        self.Entry1.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry1.configure(width=122)

        self.Text1 = tk.Text(top)
        self.Text1.place(relx=0.069, rely=0.634, relheight=0.296, relwidth=0.889)

        self.Text1.configure(background="white")
        self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(width=128)
        self.Text1.configure(wrap="word")

    def getTemp(self):
        self.plz = self.Entry1.get()
        self.data = requests.get(self.url + str(self.plz) + self.parameters)
        self.json = json.loads(self.data.text)
        self.Text1.configure(text="Stadt: " + str(self.json["name"]) + "\nTemperatur: " + str(self.json["main"]["temp"]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

I expect another error with this line:

```
self.Text1.configure(text="Stadt: " + str(this.json["name"]) + "\nTemperatur: " + str(this.json["main"]["temp"]))
```

Otherwise it should run. I didn't add much code to the gui script.

**EDIT**
Ok, now I have the full working code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 4.22
#  in conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Apr 24, 2019 01:22:16 PM CEST  platform: Darwin

import sys
import requests
import json

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import unknown_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = Toplevel1 (root)
    unknown_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Toplevel1 (w)
    unknown_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Toplevel1():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class Toplevel1:
    key = "xxx" # API KEY von openweather
    url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="
    parameters = ",DE&units=metric&appid=" + str(key)
    data = ""
    json = ""
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''self class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        top.geometry("144x142+586+143")
        top.title("New Toplevel")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        self.Button1 = tk.Button(top)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.208, rely=0.352, height=32, width=77)
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(cursor="fleur")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''GET''')
        self.Button1.configure(width=77)
        self.Button1.configure(command= lambda: self.getTemp())

        self.Entry1 = tk.Entry(top)
        self.Entry1.place(relx=0.069, rely=0.07,height=27, relwidth=0.847)
        self.Entry1.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry1.configure(cursor="fleur")
        self.Entry1.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry1.configure(width=122)

        self.Text1 = tk.Text(top)
        self.Text1.place(relx=0.069, rely=0.634, relheight=0.296, relwidth=0.889)

        self.Text1.configure(background="white")
        self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(width=128)
        self.Text1.configure(wrap="word")

    def getTemp(self):
        self.plz = self.Entry1.get()
        self.data = requests.get(self.url + str(self.plz) + self.parameters)
        self.json = json.loads(self.data.text)
        self.Text1.insert(tk.END, "Stadt: " + str(self.json["name"]) + "\nTemperatur: " + str(self.json["main"]["temp"]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it's because you're using `this`instead of `self`as an argument for `getTemp` and then use `self`in the same method without passing it as an argument?

Comment: Changed all to `self`, still not working. But thank you, this was a good idea to try.

Comment: I imagine that the traceback will be different now.

Comment: No. It's still `File "gui.py", line 105, in getTemp
    self.plz = self.Entry1.get()
AttributeError: Toplevel1 instance has no attribute 'Entry1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of edits:

- Change `this` to `self`. Try to use one unique keyword for the entire class.
- For the `command` configure for *Button1*, either use:

  `self.Button1.configure(command = self.getTemp) #without the paranthesis` OR
  `self.Button1.configure(command = lambda: self.getTemp())`

Comment: That's it! Thanks! :)

Comment: @123php just to explain why you need to remove paranthesis - the compiler will run the command (if paranthesis is present) and the Entry widget is still not defined. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned `self.Entry1 = tk.Entry(top)` in your `__init__`. Then you reference the entry by `this.Entry1 ...` in your `getTemp(this)` method. This fails because `Entry1` can only be found under `self`. Change all `this` to `self` and it should do.

Answer (score 0):

You want `self`, not `this`.

```
self.plz = self.Entry1.get()
```

This is Python, not Java. (Note also that the name `self` is explicitly passed into the method as a first argument. In theory, you could use `this` as the name, rather than `self`, but the latter is an absolutely universal standard, so please don't.)

**Update**:

Your line

```
self.Button1.configure(command=self.getTemp())
```

comes before

```
self.Entry1 = tk.Entry(top)
```

So, `self.getTemp()` is being called before `self.Entry1` is defined.